# Summing value when column id is equal SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

[image: Example]

Say I want to go from the first table to the second by summing up the value column where b is equal but also keeping a as a column. How would I do this in SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite doesn't support window functions, so a correlated subquery is a pretty simple method:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.value) from t t2 where t2.b = t.b) as sumb
from t;
```